# Pulling s_categories table from database to someone.tpl in shopware 5

Tags: smarty, shopware, shopware5

I want to pull the data from the s_categories table in the database to the tpl file I want and use it as an array, but I couldn't find how to do this in smarty. (Note: {php}{/php} doesn't work.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in smarty, you need a plugin that provides this data to the template to use it there. Smarty is a template engine and should not be used for accessing data from the database - this is the wrong layer of the application to do such things.

All things are covered in the plugin startup guide: https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/plugin-quick-start/#search-results

Comment: So if I send array from php file to tpl using controller, will it work?